# What files to update?

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed api through composer in my local machine and its working fine locally.But when I uploaded 1 tumbler folder from local to shared host from vendor folder. Its not working for shared hosting. Seems like laravel has made changes in the code at some other files too. Please help.

Error I am getting is:

```
FatalErrorException in TumblererviceProvider.php line 80:
Class 'Tumblr\API\Client' not found
```

Comment: Looks like an issue here: [Tumblr - GitHub](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/issues/24)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I didn't installed my api through composer as its shared hosting. I installed it on my local machine through composer and don't know what composer made changes.. its not duplicate

Comment: I have reopened the question. But check if you can download the latest version from GitHub and try it out?

Comment: it's happen for class autoload,try re-upload /vendor/composer folder,and then test again

Comment: I wouldn't use shared hosting for projects that necessitate root and privileged access. Much less of a headache to just go ahead and use a VPS.